# search multiple terms in taffydb

Tags: javascript, taffydb

If I make a TAFFYDB database like this:

```
customerDB.insert({
   "custID":"JONMI",
   "custName": "MIKE JONES",
   "custCity": "CHICAGO"
});
```

I can query by each individual term, like customer name:

```
var cName="MIKE";
customerDB({ "custName":{like:cName}}).each(function (record,recordnumber) {
```

but is there a way to search by any term in a single query?
By that I mean if I search by MIKE or CHICAGO or JONMI it would find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the TaffyDB [documentation](http://taffydb.com/writing_queries.html):

```
customerDB([ {"custName":{likenocase:request.term}},
               {"custCity":{likenocase:request.term}}, 
               {"custID":{likenocase:request.term}} ] 
             ).each(function (record,recordnumber) {
```

this is treaded like a logical "OR"